# How change Table Rows from another method

Tags: android

I have Table Rows at 1st method with 2 TextViews

```
final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tl.setStretchAllColumns(true);
tl.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText(nameOne);
    textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textview.setTextSize(20);
    textview.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    tr.addView(textview);


    TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
    textview2.setText(nameTwo);
    textview2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textview2.setTextSize(20);
    textview2.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    tr.addView(textview2);

    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Then I trying get/change second TextView in the row, but it doesnt works. How to get permission for the changes table rows?

```
public void anotherMethod(){
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    TableRow t = (TableRow) v;

    TextView secondTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(1);
    String secondText = secondTextView.getText().toString();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "second - " + secondText);
}
```

*Sorry for my english, I hope you`ll understand my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that the code below will help you.

```
public void anotherMethod(){
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    int tableRowIndex = 0;
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(tableRowIndex);
    int textViewIndex = 1;
    TextView textView = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(textViewIndex);
    textView.setText("New Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the id for the TableRow like this:

```
public class yourClass { 

     int tableRowID = 123456;
     final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);


     private void firstMethod() { 

          tr.setId(tableRowID);
          ......

     }

     private void secondMethod () { 
         TableRow tr = findViewByID(tableRowID);
         TextView secondTextView = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(1);
         ....

     }
}
```

You can also set the tag for the tableRow:

```
tr.setTag("TableRow");
```